# I tried to generate access token through api

Tags: docusignapi

I tried to generate access token through api but I am unable to get code I tried to generate through the apis

Unable to generate access token

```
GET https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth? response_type=code &scope=signature &client_id={CLIENT_ID} &state=a39fh23hnf23 &redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI} 

POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Authorization: Basic 
   BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATOR_AND_SECRET_KEYS

grant_type=authorization_code&authorization_code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

But I received the following response

```
{
   "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be any of a number of issues. Did you receive back an `authorization_code`? Did you use the `authorization_code` in less than two minutes (it's time limited).

There are other potential issues too. Google for "docusign invalid_grant"

Did you properly create and encode the BASIC authorization field?

For the best results I recommend that you use an OAuth Authorization Code Grant client library. They exist for most every web stack / language.